# Download files from Page with predefined filter

Tags: pdf, download, wget

I want to download all *.pdf files from a website.
(https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/PLENAR/)

But when I open the URL, only the first 50 documents are listed (and also downloaded with WGET)
So I changed the URL in my command including the search parameters, which works fine when I open it in the browser (it shows all 145) but it does not work in my command.

Can you give me a hint or help me please?

```
wget --recursive --level=1 --no-directories --no-host-directories --no-check-certificate --accept pdf https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/PLENAR/index.shtml?SUCH=&xdocumentUri=%2FPAKT%2FPLENAR%2Findex.shtml&pageNumber=&GP=XXV&STEP=&FBEZ=FP_007&NRBRBV=NR&R_SISTEI=SI&requestId=76AAFD95E4&LISTE=&jsMode=&STATT=ALLE&listeId=1070&EING=ALLE
```

Something similar (or more difficult) I would like to achieve with the URL https://www.parlament.gv.at/SERV/STAT/IND/

In the second case, I even need to make a selection first, which I have no idea to solve.

Thank you already in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474482/why-wget-ignores-query-string-in-the-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows `wget.exe` (GNU Wget 1.10.2) it indeed doesn't work right (without quoting the URL there are errors for the part of the URL after the first `&`, and with double quotes around the URL the `?` somehow gets translated to `@` by wget.exe, invalidating the URL). OTOH, on Debian Jessie (GNU Wget 1.16) it works just fine (with double quotes around the URL) - but I assume you're on Windows, or otherwise using an older `wget`.

The "other" answer in the SO question linked by w32sh (in comments) seems to work, just put the URL in a text file (no quoting) and replace the URL in your command with `-i URL.txt`.

As for the second case you've got, you need to build an URL for HTTP GET request with the parameters you require.

1. If you look at the page HTML source (using "View page source" or a built-in page inspector in the brower) you should find the `form` tag which says:

   < form id="filterFormFP_023" action="/SERV/STAT/IND/index.shtml" method="get"  [...] >

   So, the first part of your URL should be `https://www.parlament.gv.at/SERV/STAT/IND/index.shtml` (basically adding the `action` parameter to the host name).
2. Within the form, notice a `fieldset` containing the input fields.
   "Zeitraum" dropdown:

   < select id="FP_023_GP" [...] name="GP">

   Radio buttons "Teile" / "Personen":

   < input id="FP_023_R_TP_1" type="radio" [...] value="T" checked="" name="R_TP">
   < input id="FP_023_R_TP_2" type="radio" [...] value="P" name="R_TP">

   Further dropdowns:

   < select id="FP_023_T" [...] name="T">

   < select id="FP_023_PADT" [...] name="PADT">

   et cetera.
3. From those fields you need to take the `name` and the value you want to query with and append them in the URL so that it becomes `https://www.parlament.gv.at/SERV/STAT/IND/index.shtml?name1=value1&name2?value2&name3=value3&name4=value4` (and so on). Notice the `?` before the parameter list and `&` between each parameter name-value pair. For the dropdowns (`select` tags) use whatever there is listed in the `option` tag `value` attribute as the value. Eg. `https://www.parlament.gv.at/SERV/STAT/IND/index.shtml?GP=XXIV&R_TP=T&T=B&PADT=178`.
4. Finally, test the URL in browser, and if it works as if you'd made the query in the browser, put the URL in a text file and use the above method with `wget`.

Please also note that if some of the parameter values contain spaces or [non-ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Code_chart) characters, you likely need to use [proper encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailed description and explanation! This really helped me a lot.